# Significado funcion php

Tags: php

Estoy utilizando un código que me han dejado, pero no se que quiere decir esta función:

```
return $a < $b ? -1 : 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente no es una función. Es una expresión que trabaja con un operador de comparación `?` denominado *Operador Ternario*.

```
return $a < $b ? -1 : 1;
```

Su interpretación es similar a esto:

```
// si $a es menor que $b...
if($a < $b) {
    return -1;
}
else {
    return 1;
}
```

Al contrario que ocurre con los `if`, donde es habitual y se comporta perfectamente, no se recomienda *anidar o apilar* varias expresiones.

```
$a < $b ? -1 : $c ? -2 : 1;
```

Para tal caso, se debería usar los paréntesis para establecer preferencias y obtener el resultado deseado o decantarse por una estructura con una lectura más evidente para evitar errores. Como por ejemplo `if`.

Answer (score 6):

Es un `if` compacto, simplificado.
Lo que hace es una comprobación de `$a` es menor a `$b` si lo es, devuelve `-1` y sino `1`

digamos la estructura `<comparación> ? cierto : falso;`

Otra manera de hacerlo seria así

```
$r = 1;
if ($a < $b) $r= -1;
return $r;
```